# Simple test on a large range of devices (emulators)

Tags: android, testing, android-emulator, automated-tests, monkey

I find that I often introduce subtle - but critical - bugs in my app  on older versions of Android.
For instance, who knew that this would crash android 4.1.2

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" tools:targetApi="19">true</item>
```

In the early stages of the my I was very fond of the monkeyrunner for doing some stress testing. I can see that it is also possible to script it to perform some specific tasks.
This is all very nice, but I would like in addition the ability to run this little test script on every supported API level. Does android have a framework for 
running something on a range of various emulators?